# How to detect keypresses in jQuery regardless of layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, tampermonkey

So basically i am trying to connect clicking links to keys in Tampermonkey. First I tried e.which, but it didn't work with different layouts. Then I tried e.code, but for some reason it only detects pressing the B key (see code below). What did I do wrong?

```js
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    if(e.сode == "KeyN") {
        document.getElementById("nextimage").click();
    } else if(e.code == "KeyB") {
        document.getElementById("previmage").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation for `keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/). There are many differences between that event and, say, "keydown" in regards to what is captured and reported in the event object.

Comment: @dacoconutnut try this instead 'e.key'

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper this method does not work regardless of layout, i need the physical key that is pressed, i searched how to do that but it detected only 1 key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the KEY itself instead of the code. The toUpperCase() function will detect lowercase or uppercase :

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    if(e.key.toUpperCase() == "N") {
        alert("yay!")
    } else if(e.key.toUpperCase() == "B") {
        alert("nay");
    }
});
```

Here's a reference with the different key codes: https://keycode.info/

Comment: this method does not work regardless of layout, i need the physical key that is pressed, i searched how to do that but it detected only 1 key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read keys.

Make sure you have the JQuery reference.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
      alert('You pressed - ' + event.key.toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and here is javascript in case:

```
const myText = document.getElementById('myText');
document.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);
function logKey(e) {
  myText.textContent += e.key.toUpperCase();
  if(e.key.toUpperCase() == 'N')
     alert("You Pressed N  key");
}
```

and

```
<p id="myText"></p>
```

Comment: this method does not work regardless of layout, i need the physical key that is pressed, i searched how to do that but it detected only 1 key?

Comment: If it is working here, then you have other issues with your code.